# Typing a collection of merge functions for a given type

Tags: typescript

If I have a type such as:

```js
interface ITest {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}
```

I would like to be able to generically define a type which can be a 'collection' of functions to merge a given property of the type.

I can define an individual 'Merger' something like:

```js
type Merger<T, K extends keyof T> = (a: T[K], b: T[K]) => T[K];
```

But I'd look to be able to have a full collection of these such as:

```js
const mergers: Mergers<ITest> = {
  a: (a: number, b: number) => a + b,   // should work with no error
  b: (a: string, b: number) => `${a}: ${b}`,    // this one should error
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Your `Merger` sounds a lot like what we call a `Semigroup` in functional programming (category theory). A  `Semigroup` is something that has `concat()`.
Here is a bit of info on how to use `Semigroup` in a library called *fp-ts*: https://dev.to/gcanti/getting-started-with-fp-ts-semigroup-2mf7

Comment: @tomaj This sounds like an interesting read - I'll check it out

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use a mapped type to map over the keys of `T`. You will even get contextual types for the parameters:

```
type Merger<T, K extends keyof T> = (a: T[K], b: T[K]) => T[K];
type Mergers<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Merger<T, P>
}

const mergers: Mergers<ITest> = {
  a: (a, b) => a + b,   // ok, contextualy typed a and b 
  b: (a: string, b: number) => `${a}: ${b}`,    // error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4FgBQ6CWA7GwoBmAhgMbBwCSAKsAM7wLpxxEBcc2ArgLYBG+AbiZxe7elBwBzIWmYl2vCBAA2wIthmoMaGAE8w5ALL5J+ADxUANHADScUHmwATWnADWwXRAJwqAPjgAXjgACjZfAG0bAF1rUUiYgEoggKoo6Jk9AzhjKFMoWgsA4MZZOAiABTgcd09vX2j2XPyLawq-dC10EghsejhuE3xaJqGCs2o6GGLEYXCwuOTAgKI4AGoRa2YAem24CDdrHtwHTiJlXTgs4CcWFmcROGF4sLEYCWxJOPYuPnwlgIAAwAJAgiEh2KDeEhAVsdnt8FBoJ0gA)

Comment: Fantastic! Solves the problem perfectly, many thanks